# Html Agility Pack - Problem selecting subnode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I want to export my Asics running plan to iCal and since Asics do not offer this service, I decided to build a little scraper for my own personal use. What I want to do is to take all the scheduled runs from my plan and generate an iCal feed based on that. I am using C# and Html Agility Pack.

What I want to do is iterate through all my scheduled runs (they are div nodes). Then next I want to select a few different nodes with my run nodes. My code looks like this:

```
foreach (var run in doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='scheduleTable']").SelectNodes("//div[@class='pTdBox']"))
{
    number++;
    string date = run.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='date']").InnerText;
    string type = run.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='menu']").InnerHtml;
    string distance = run.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='distance']").InnerHtml;
    string description = run.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='description']").InnerHtml;
    ViewData["result"] += "Dato: " + date + "<br />";
    ViewData["result"] += "Tyep: " + type + "<br />";
    ViewData["result"] += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
    ViewData["result"] += "Description: " + description + "<br />";
    ViewData["result"] += run.InnerHtml.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;") + "<br />" + "<br />" + "<br />";
}
```

My problem is that `run.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='date']").InnerText` does not select the node with the given XPath within the given run node. It selects the first node that matches the XPath in the entire document.

How can I select the single node with the given XPath within the current node?

Thank you.

**Update**

I tried updating my XPath string to this:

```
string date = run.SelectSingleNode(".div[@class='date']").InnerText;
```

This should select the `<div class="date"></div>` element within the current node, right? Well, I tried this but got this error:

> Expression must evaluate to a
>   node-set. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathException:
>   Expression must evaluate to a
>   node-set.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not solid (at all) in XPath, but doesn't `//` mean anywhere from root?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp: Seems to me that you need something along the lines of `child::div[@class='data']`, but again, I don't know for sure. At all.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

A few things that will help you when working with *HtmlAgilityPack* and *XPath* expressions.

If `run` is an `HtmlNode`, then:

1. `run.SelectNodes("//div[@class='date']")`

   Will will behave exactly like `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='date']")`
2. `run.SelectNodes("./div[@class='date']")`

   Will give you all the `<div>` nodes that are children of `run` node. It won't search deeper, only at the very next depth level.
3. `run.SelectNodes(".//div[@class='date']")`

   Will return all the `<div>` nodes with that class attribute, but not only next to the `run` node, but also will search in depth (every possible descendant of it)

You will have to choose between 2. or 3., depending on which one satisfy your needs :)

Comment: OMG, you simply save my life. I just confused between 1 and 3. Thanks MAN.

Comment: @Soren The same happened to me :)

Answer (score 3):

In XPATH, `//` means all children and grand children below the current node. So you need to come up with a more restrictive XPATH expression. If you provide the real HTML, and what you're looking for exactly, we can help you dig further.

About the error you have:

`.div[@class='date']` is invalid because `.` is sticked to `div`. You could use `div[@class='date']`, or `./div[@class='date']` which I believe are equivalent. This is because `.` is an [XPATH axe](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp), which is an alias for `self` and means "the current node".

Comment: @Simon Mourier - I am also trying to get the data from a node having attribute "name" but it's not taking it

Comment: @student - you should write another question