# HtmlAgilityPack and selecting Nodes and Subnodes

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Hope somebody can help me.

Let´s say I have a `html` document that contains multiple `divs` like this example:

```html
<div class="search_hit">
    <span prop="name">Richard Winchester</span>
    <span prop="company">Kodak</span>
    <span prop="street">Arlington Road 1</span>
</div>
<div class="search_hit">
    <span prop="name">Ted Mosby</span>
    <span prop="company">HP</span>
    <span prop="street">Arlington Road 2</span>
</div>
```

I´m using `HtmlAgilityPack` to get the `html` document. What I need to know is how can I get the spans for each `search_hit-div`?

My first thought was something like this:

```cs
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']"))
{
     foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("//span[@prop]"))
     {
     }
}
```

Each `div` should be an object with the included spans as properties:

```cs
public class Record
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
}
```

And this List shall be filled then:

```cs
public List<Record> Results = new List<Record>();
```

But the `XPATH` I'm using is not doing a search in the sub node as it should do. It seams that it searches the whole document again and again.

I mean I already got it working in that way that I just get the the spans of the whole page, but then I have no relation between the `spans` and `divs`. Means, I don´t know anymore which `span` is related to which `div`.

Does somebody know a solution? I already played around that much that I'm totally confused now. :)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: See my answer for to ways of parsing your code (full working solution).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The following works for me. The important bit is just as BeniBela noted to add a dot in second call to 'SelectNodes'.

```
List<Record> lstRecords=new List<Record>();
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']"))
{
  Record record=new Record();
  foreach (HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes(".//span[@prop]"))
  {
    string attributeValue = node2.GetAttributeValue("prop", "");
    if (attributeValue == "name")
    {
      record.Name = node2.InnerText;
    }
    else if (attributeValue == "company")
    {
      record.company = node2.InnerText;
    }
    else if (attributeValue == "street")
    {
      record.street = node2.InnerText;
    }
  }
  lstRecords.Add(record);
}
```

Answer (score 71):

If you use `//`, it searches from the document begin.

Use `.//` to search all from the current node

```
 foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes(".//span[@prop]"))
```

Or drop the prefix entirely to search just for direct children:

```
 foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("span[@prop]"))
```

Comment: If I do this:  foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes("span[@prop]")) Visual Studio is coming up with an error.

Comment: what kind of error? You can also try the `./` prefix for that. (I am actually just guessing)

Comment: I tried both and both is ending up with: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: After reading HtmlAgilityPack's source I'm pretty sure it should work like that. Perhaps the error occurs somewhere else after  reading the nodes? Or perhaps the nodes do not exist in the html file?

Comment: They do. I´ve tested it seperately. I´m getting results when just doing this: foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']"))

Comment: And this is also working: foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']/descendant-or-self::span[@prop]")) but here i have no relation between spans and divs because i´m just having the spans

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181014/html-agility-pack-problem-selecting-subnode/6182495#6182495

Answer (score 3):

First of all, take a look at this: **[Html Agility Pack - Problem selecting subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181014/html-agility-pack-problem-selecting-subnode/6182495#6182495)**

Here is a full working solution for your question:

```
IList<Record> results = new List<Record>();
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']")) {
    var record = new Record();
    record.Name = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@prop='name']").InnerText;
    record.company = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@prop='company']").InnerText;
    record.street = node.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@prop='street']").InnerText;
    results.Add(record);
}
```

If you read the question I pointed you to, you will see that doing `./span[@prop='name']` is exactly the same, since those `span` nodes are (direct) children of the `div` node.

---

If the `span` nodes do not have those `prop` attributes, and you want to assign them depending on the order they appear, you can do:

```
foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='search_hit']")) {
    var spanNodes = node.SelectNodes("./span");
    var record = new Record();
    record.Name = spanNodes[0].InnerText;
    record.company = spanNodes[1].InnerText;
    record.street = spanNodes[2].InnerText;
    results.Add(record);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shame on me :)

All of you were right.

I found the problem. This NullReferenceException kept nagging me so I spent more time to look at it in detail.
In between all those divs there was one div with the same "class='search-hit'" attribute but without the spans inside. Thats why it throughs an error at the second loop.

```
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@prop]/ancestor::div[@class='search_hit']"))
   {
        Record rec = new Record();
        foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in node.SelectNodes(".//span[@prop]"))
           {
           }
           rList.Results.Add(rec);
   }
```

The code above is working.

Thank you guys for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

I used that. class convert id

```
  HtmlNodeCollection nodes = dokuman.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='search_hit']//span[@prop]");


            for (int i = 0; i < nodes .Count; i++)
        {
            var record = new Record();


                record.Name = links[i].InnerText;   results.Add(record);  }
```