# Html agility pack, how to add console output to List

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I am trying to output some strings from a certain website and i want to add each row into a List.
The output i am looking for looks like this:

```
string url = "https://thepiratebay.org/search/rick%20and%20morty/0/99/0";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

        //upload list
        List<string> uploadList = new List<string>();

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResult']/tr/td/font[@class='detDesc']"))
        {
            var input =  node.InnerHtml.ToString();
            //The [^0-9] expression is used to find any character that is NOT a digit, will replace with empty string
            input = Regex.Replace(input, "([^0-9]+)"," ");

            Console.WriteLine(input);
         }
```

I need to store every row into a list in order to process each element of data and i can't manage to set `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResult']/tr/td/font[@class='detDesc']")` into an array

Comment: what do you mean by you can't manage to set an IEnumerable into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your input into the list by using

`uploadList.Add(Input);`

in the foreach loop instead of printing it to the console and the somehow read it from there again.

And you might want to select the `tr`, `td` and `font` children as described in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15004032/2960293

Comment: i did exactly like this. i forgot to answer the question.
Other than this, I also modified the regex a little, so if you want to see the output, here it is:
` foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='searchResult']/tr/td/font[@class='detDesc']"))
            {

                
                string input = Regex.Replace(node.InnerHtml.ToString(), @"(?s)^.*?(\d{2})\D*(\d{2})\D*(\d{4}).*", "$1 $2 $3")
                uploadList.Add(input)`