# Web scraping from dynamic content table on Powershell using PowerHTML module

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm getting an error when I try to read contents form a table on the web page described in the script. Can anyone please help me with a solution to fix it. Thanks.

```
@mklement0, Thanks for the detailed explanation. With your help, I was able to extract the table information. However, I'm still unable to extract table rows as it's still returned as null. Can you please help? Please see below. Thanks.
 
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$res = $wc.DownloadString('https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html')
$html = ConvertFrom-Html -Content $res

$ScrapeData=[System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$ScrapeData+=$n
$table = $html.SelectNodes('//table') | Where-Object { $_.HasClass("display") -or $_.HasClass("dataTable")}

foreach ($row in $table.SelectNodes('//tr') | Where-Object { $_.HasClass("odd") -or $_.HasClass("even")} )
{
    $cnt += 1

    if ($cnt -eq 1) { continue }

    #$name= $row.SelectSingleNode('//th').innerText.Trim() | Where-Object { $_.HasClass('sorting_1')}
    $value=$row.SelectSingleNode('td').innerText.Trim() -replace "\?", " "
    $new_obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $new_obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $value
    $ScrapeData+=$new_obj 
}

Write-Output 'Extracted Table Information'
$table
 
Write-Output 'Extracted Book Details Parsed from HTML table'
$ScrapeData
```

[image: Extracted data as below]

Comment: What error (or incorrect behaviour) are you getting? What are you *expecting* to happen instead? Your question is unlikely to get any useful answers unless you can provide some *specific* information about the problem…

Comment: Try following : $table = $html.Descendants('table') | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq 'example' }

Comment: The function ConvertFrom-Html can return different types.  To see the type use Write-Host $html.GetType().  In this case the return type HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode does not support SelectNodes() but does support Descendants()

Comment: @jdweng: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode` _does_ have a [`.SelectNodes()`](https://documentation.help/HtmlAgilityPack/0a07ee34-916d-57b7-2f6b-f576a35b409d.htm) method.

Comment: @mklement0 : You do not understand the problem and did not even try to execute the code.  The code gives following error : Method invocation failed because [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode] does not contain a method named 'SelectNodes'.

Comment: @jdweng, I pointed you to the documentation that proves that said type has such a method, and when I execute `($doc = [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]::new()).LoadHtml('<html><body>ha</body></html>'); $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes`, I see the overloads for this method.  Perhaps you have a very old version of the assembly? P.S.: I did execute the code, and I see a very different problem: `$table` ends up `$null` because of a broken `.HasClass()` call, causing the subsequent `$table.SelectNodes()` call to fail with "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: P.S., @jdweng, on a meta note: Instead of leveling gratuitous ad-hominems ("You do not understand the problem"), I suggest exercising due diligence, which involves at least addressing the blatant contradiction between your claim and the documentation I had pointed you to. HTML Agility Pack questions that use the `.SelectNodes()` method date back to at least 2013(!) - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15003409/45375, for example.

Comment: @mklement0 : Look at source code : https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs

Comment: @jdweng, that is a `partial` definition of the class. The method definition is [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/f745398b029ebd458f6aec16d066c7268ae3e4c4/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.Xpath.cs#L40).

Comment: Your method is only avialable when the HTMLNode is inherited from IXPathNavigable.  The c# library which is where I found the solution is not inherited from IXPathNavigable.

Comment: @mklement0 : Your method is only avialable when the HTMLNode is inherited from IXPathNavigable. The c# library which is where I found the solution is not inherited from IXPathNavigable.

Comment: @jdweng: Firstly: the  method is part of an _implicit_ implementation of [`IXPathNavigable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XPath.IXPathNavigable) (a _standard .NET interface_), so even if you consumed the assembly from C#, it would be directly available, without a cast. Secondly - a moot point in this case - PowerShell even surfaces _explicit_ interface members as if they were direct members of a class.

Comment: @mklement0 : Your method doesn't work in either Powershell or c#.  I tried both.  When you try in c# with VS it doesn't exist.

Comment: @jdweng, install the `PSParseHtml` module (`Install-Module PSParseHTML`), then run `Import-Module PSParseHTML`, then `($doc = [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]::new()).LoadHtml('<html><body>ha</body></html>'); $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes` to see that the method is there. I have no idea what you're working with, but it's clearly not the official HTML Agility Pack. Please consider deleting all your comments here (after which I'll delete mine) - they are not only unhelpful, but also confusing distractions.

Comment: @mklement0 : Why don't you explain solutions better.  What does following mean :"can only ever retrieve static HTML source code, not dynamically rendered HTML."?  The root cause of issue is the Webclient is not executing the scripts so the table is empty and has not rows.  The table tbody only has a header and footer.

Comment: @jdweng, it means what you're describing. I've updated the answer to spell it out more explicitly; thanks for the suggestion. It looks like all open questions have been answered now, so I encourage you to delete your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The ***fundamental* problem** is that the **[`System.Net.WebClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Net.WebClient)** class, via its `.DownloadString()` method, as well as PowerShell's web cmdlets - **[`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)** and **[`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)** - **can only ever retrieve *static* HTML *source code*, not *dynamically rendered* HTML.**<sup>[1]</sup>

  - To support **extracting content loaded *dynamically*** - via *scripts* embedded in the source code that only execute when the page is *rendered in a browser* - you **need a *full web browser* that you can *control programmatically*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77822052/45375).
  - *Interactively*, most browsers offer:

    - a view of the *static HTML source code* of a page by right-clicking and selecting a shortcut-menu command such as `View Page Source` or `Show Page Source`.
    - a view of the *dynamically generated HTML* by right-clicking and selecting a command such as `Inspect` or `Inspect Element`
- The *immediate* problems are [*update*: the cited code is from the original form of the question]:

  - Note:

    - The following assumes use of the `ConvertFrom-Html` cmdlet from the   [`PSParseHTML`](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML) module, whose use your code  suggests.

      - By default, it returns `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode` instances from the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/) .NET library.
    - **While the explanations below point to solutions, they are *hypothetical*, as they would require the *dynamically generated* HTML to operate on**, which, as noted `.DownloadString()` cannot provide.
      Specifically, the source code *doesn't contain any table rows* - they are populated dynamically; also, the `<table>` element has only *one* class, `display`.
  - `$_.HasClass('display dataTable')` looks for a *single* class name literally named `display dataTable`, whereas `class="display dataTable"` in the dynamically generated HTML means that the element has *two* classes, `display` and `dataTable`. Therefore your method call always returns `$false`.

    - As a result, the `$table = ...` assignment ends up as `$null`, which then predictably causes an attempt to call a *method* on it to fail. Specifically, `$table.SelectNodes('//tr')` results in error `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`
    - The logic you were looking for is probably to find elements with class `display` *as well as* `dataTable`, which requires `$_.HasClass("display") -and $_.HasClass("dataTable")`
  - `$_.HasClass("odd", "even")` *would* have become a problem, because the method only accepts a *single* string.

    - The logic you were looking for is probably to find elements with class `odd` *or* class `even`, which requires `$_.HasClass("odd") -or $_.HasClass("even")`

---

<sup>[1] In PowerShell's *legacy*, ships-with-Windows, Windows-only edition, *Windows PowerShell* (whose latest and *last* version is v5.1) - as opposed to the modern, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition - you *may* still be able to use built-in features to access dynamic content, but - given that these features rely on the long-obsolete *Internet Explorer* - this will work with fewer and fewer websites over time.</sup>

Comment: The OP already has a method that works.  The only issue was to use Descendants() instead of SelectNode.  Why come up with a completely new solution?  Why say there is a fundamental issue when there is no issue.  Why didn't you even try my solution.  All you did is say I did something wrong when I did nothing wrong.  You cannot use SelectNodes in HTMLAgilityPack when you have a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.   You just have to use Descendants instead.

Comment: @jdweng, please consider deleting _all_ your comments here and, on a meta note, consider the following going forward: Whenever you're about to post a comment, first consider whether such a comment (a) is based on a true understanding of the problem at hand and (b) if so, whether it truly _contributes toward finding a solution_ or offers - properly framed as such - _generally helpful pointers_. If neither condition is met, please refrain from commenting.

Comment: @mklement0, Thanks for your detailed feedback. You have fixed half of my issues already. I was able to extract the table data but for some reason, it's not returning individual values of table rows. Can you please help? I have updated the code and screenshot of the extract data.

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped, @RoshanFernando, but, on a meta note: please don't substantially alter your question after answers have been given: it invalidates the existing answers and causes confusion for future readers. I suggest reverting your question to its original form.

Comment: @RoshanFernando, as for why your updated code is not returning the individual rows: That is due to the fundamental problem pointed out in the answer:
The class names you're looking for on the `<tr>` elements _do not exist in the static HTML source code_ - they only exist in the
_dynamically generated HTML_, which neither `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString()` nor PowerShell's web cmdlets are able to retrieve.

Comment: @jdweng, it can be inferred from my previous comments, but let me spell out a summary: You made an incorrect claim about the HTML Agility Pack API,
and you provided an alternative solution that _could not have made a difference_, because the real problem with the code was unrelated to the use
of `.SelectNodes()` (which works just fine). In short: Not only did you not contribute to a solution, you sowed confusion with your false claims about HTML Agility Pack,  exacerbated by doubling down on those claims.