# HtmlAgilityPack SelectNodes, Disposing

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to do some screen scraping using HtmlAgilityPack using `SelectNodes` and getting some values from each node returned

Here is the code

```
private readonly HtmlDocument _document = new HtmlDocument();

public void ParseValues(string html)
{
    _document.LoadHtml(html);
    var tables = _document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

    foreach (var table in tables)
    {
        _document.LoadHtml(table.OuterHtml);
        var value = _document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody[1]/tr/td[0]");
    }
}
```

But I have noticed that when trying to select children with inside the foreach loop it actually searches from the document root. Something that is really annoying.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to select the values from each table returned from `SelectNodes` without having to create new document instance from the `HtmlDocument`?
2. Is there a way to dispose `HtmlDocument`, because I noticed that there is a memory leak every time I use `_document.LoadHtml(html)`;

Answer (score 1):

*(for a more detailed explanation, see [Html Agility Pack - Problem selecting subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181014/html-agility-pack-problem-selecting-subnode/6182495#6182495))*

---

You **don't** have to create another `HtmlDocument` object, or load another HTML into it. You just have to do:

```
foreach (var table in tables)
{
    var value = table.SelectSingleNode(".//tbody[1]/tr/td[0]");
}
```

The key is to use `.//tbody` instead of `//tbody`.

Comment: So what about disposing the HtmlDocument ?

Comment: Also i get this error if i did not created a new instance of HtmlDocument. startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.

Comment: I'm just answering to your 1st question.

Comment: I don't understand... does that error appears if you use my `foreach` instead of yours?

Comment: Please, share the HTML you're parsing, so that I can debug it here, and give you a more detailed answer. You can use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or a similar service.