# Looping through HtmlNodes and collecting data gives me the same result every time

Tags: c#, async-await, html-agility-pack

I have an `async` method which calls a mapper for turning HTML string into an `IEnumerable`:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MovieRatingScrape>> GetMovieRatingsAsync(string username, int page)
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"/betyg/{username}?p={page}");
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return new MovieRatingsHtmlMapper().Map(html);
}

...

public class MovieRatingsHtmlMapper : HtmlMapperBase<IEnumerable<MovieRatingScrape>>
{
    // In reality, this method belongs to base class with signature T Map(string html)
    public IEnumerable<MovieRatingScrape> Map(string html)
    {
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        return Map(htmlDocument);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<MovieRatingScrape> Map(HtmlDocument item)
    {
        var movieRatings = new List<MovieRatingScrape>();
        var nodes = item.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='list']/tr");

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            var title = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[1]/a")?.InnerText;

            movieRatings.Add(new MovieRatingScrape
            {
                Date = DateTime.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("//td[2]")?.InnerText),
                Slug = node.SelectSingleNode("//td[1]/a[starts-with(@href, '/film/')]")?
                    .GetAttributeValue("href", null)?
                    .Replace("/film/", string.Empty),
                SwedishTitle = title,
                Rating = node.SelectNodes($"//td[3]/i[{XPathHasClass("fa-star")}]").Count
            });
        }

        return movieRatings;
    }
}
```

The resulting list `movieRatings` contains copies of the same object, but when I look at the HTML and when I debug and view the `HtmlNode node` they differ as they are supposed to.

Either I'm blind to something really obvious, or I am hitting some `async` issue which I do not grasp. Any ideas? I should be getting 50 unique objects out of this call, now I am only getting the first 50 times.

Thank you in advance, Viktor.

Edit: Adding some screenshots to show my predicament. Look at locals `InnerHtml` (`node`) and title for item 1 and 2 of the `foreach` loop.

Edit 2: Managed to reproduce on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/A2I4CQ

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you manually step through the foreach loop, does the `movieRatings` list update correctly?

Comment: `public T Map(string html)` I don't see the definition of type `T`.

Comment: @StuartAitken No, it does not. `node` seems to be correct, but `title` and `movieRatings` get the wrong data.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I'm sorry, I made a simplification for the purpose of the question, see updated code.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. My advice is to grab a logging framework, and log to a file at various points inside your code, until you find the source of duplication.

Comment: @Viktor Try LINQ. `movieRatings = nodes.Select(node => new MovieRatingScrape{ /*Date=node.selectNodes.... , Slug = , Title = ... etc... */ }).ToList();` This won't necessarily work, but it's an alternative route to the same result. Would be interesting to see what happens.

Comment: @StuartAitken LINQ is producing the same result with `.Select()`. This is really odd and I don't know how to proceed without debugging HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: @Viktor I guess it's time to ask the HTML Agility folk! https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/issues

Comment: off topic!  but you are returning an IEnumerable?  what not use yield return MovieRatingScape, that way you can avoid waiting for the list to be built before returning, my suggestion

Comment: @Aaron.S Yes, off topic! No, but I was yielding before I got to tearing my code apart looking for the culprit of this.

Comment: @StuartAitken Created an issue now. I successfully created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A2I4CQ), very thankful that it is not only on my machine. So either my code or HAP code. Probably my code somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html Agility Pack SelectSingleNode giving always same result in iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185404/html-agility-pack-selectsinglenode-giving-always-same-result-in-iteration)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.//` and not `//`

Here is the fixed Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dZkSRN

---

`//` will search anywhere in the document

`.//` will search anywhere in the current node

Comment: Thanks, I will give you the correct answer! Then it all makes sense. I don't know how I missed that particular detail, I thought I read that `//` meant searching from current node down.

Answer (score -1):

i am not super sure how to describe this but your issue is here (i think)

```
//table[@class='list']/tr"
```

specifically the //

I experienced the same thing while looking for a span.  i had to use something similar

```
    var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[@class='itemRow productItemWrapper']");
            foreach(HtmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                var nodeDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                nodeDoc.LoadHtml(node.InnerHtml);

string name = nodeDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='productDetailTitle']").InnerText;
            }
```