# Select a node based on name in html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a form element like this:

```
<form autocomplete="on" class="class1" action="action1" method="post" name="name1">
</form>
```

There are 5 forms in webpage, I can access forms using class attribute:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@class='class1']")
```

I am trying to capture this by using name attribute but it is coming null:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@name='name1']")
```

Asking this question as [recommended by @Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181014/html-agility-pack-problem-selecting-subnode/6184558?noredirect=1#comment38501491_6184558)

Comment: Cross-check: What does `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form[@name]")` give you?

Comment: @Tomalak - it is giving me the collection of all the forms now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't know why but ) This is giving the desired form:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//form[@name='name1']")
```

Comment: This is very strange.

Comment: @Tomalak - really, I actually tried your suggestion. It gave me the collection of forms, then I tried this code and it did not returned null this time

Comment: `SelectSingleNode` internally does the same thing `SelectNodes` does. If you get a result with one of the functions, you *should* get a result with the other as well.